# Mule Amqp plugin and Mel

Tags: rabbitmq, mule, amqp, mule-studio

I want to post message to exchange with routing key. The message witch I want to send is from payload, but routing key I'm seting in message in inbound properties, and then I set: 
routingKey="#[message.inboundProperties.routingKey]" but it not working

```
<flow name="ExportToFk" doc:name="ExportToFk">
        <vm:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" path="rabbitSenderVM" doc:name="SendToRabbit"/>
        <scripting:component doc:name="Groovy">
            <scripting:script engine="Groovy"><![CDATA[import org.mule.api.transport.PropertyScope

def xml = payload.xml
def routingKey = payload.routing

println "XML: $xml"
println "ROUTINGKEY: $routingKey"

message.setProperty('routingKey', routingKey, PropertyScope.INBOUND)

return xml]]></scripting:script>
        </scripting:component>
        <amqp:outbound-endpoint exchangeName="${amqp.exchange}" routingKey="#[message.inboundProperties.routingKey]" responseTimeout="10000" connector-ref="AMQP_Connector" doc:name="AMQP"/>
    </flow>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue, which is currently under development: https://github.com/mulesoft/mule-transport-amqp/issues/24